# Coredata - Backup and restore with NSOpenPanel not working

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data

OSX Project:
Something strange is happening, hoping someone has a thought on the solution. I have a coredata project and I'm working on the backup/restore portion.

Initially I had hardcoded the file name and used the Applications file directory for the storage location - this all worked without an issue.

Next, I used `NSOpenPanel` to select the storage location. In this step, I used the same filename in the restore process - this worked without issue.

Last, I used `NSOpenPanel` to select the file to restore - this is the issue. I receive errors and the file is NOT opened.

Create backup method

```
  NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
  [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:NO];
  [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
  [openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];

  NSArray *pathName;
  if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
  {
    pathName = [openDlg URLs];

  }
  filePathNameBackup = [pathName objectAtIndex:0];

  NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
  [format setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS"];
  NSString *stringOfDate = [format stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

  fileNameBackup = [fileNameBackup stringByAppendingString:stringOfDate];//fileNameBackup is defined earlier as "datafile"
  fileNameBackup = [fileNameBackup stringByAppendingString:@".backup"];
  //Created a filename with a timestamp

  filePathNameBackup = [filePathNameBackup    URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameBackup];

  NSURL *urlbackup = filePathNameBackup;

  ...then the rest of the code to save the file - which does work
```

Then in the restore method I have the following:

```
  NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
  [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
  [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
  [openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
  [openDlg setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"backup"]];

  NSArray *pathName;
  if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
  {
     pathName = [openDlg URLs];

   NSURL *urlbackup = [pathname objectAtIndex:0];

  ... Then the rest of the restore method
```

The above does NOT work, I receive an error when creating the store - states it can not open file.

```
  NSPersistentStore *restoreStore = [migrationCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:urlbackup options:nil error:nil];
```

Now the funny crazy part is if I use the file path name from the create backup method, it will work (filePathNameBackup):

```
 NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
  [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
  [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
  [openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
  [openDlg setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"backup"]];

  NSArray *pathName;
  if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
  {
     pathName = [openDlg URLs];

   NSURL *urlbackup = filePathNameBackup;

  ... Then the rest of the restore method
```

The above will work. I open the App, create a backup (Selecting the location in `NSOpenPanel` during the create backup method), change the file, save it, restore the backup, everything works!!

So why won't this work using NSOpenPanel to select the backup file?

If I NSLog the URL's, they both appear to be identical.

Summary of restore method:

```
 NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
  [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
  [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
  [openDlg setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
  [openDlg setAllowedFileTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"backup"]];

  NSArray *pathName;
  if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
  {
     pathName = [openDlg URLs];


   NSURL *urlbackup = filePathNameBackup;    //THIS WORKS (Use filename created during backup)

   NSURL *urlbackup = [pathname objectAtIndex:0]; //THIS DOESNOT WORK
```

NO THEY BOTH ARE NOT BEING USED TOGETHER - I rem out one or the other urlbackup definitions before I run the program.

Again, why wont `NSURL *urlbackup = [pathname objectAtIndex:0];` work?

Any thoughts would be appreciate, I was up late last night (this morning) and about ready to throw something. It just does not make any sense.

---[EDIT-----
The error received is error:14, unable to open database file

---[EDIT #2]----

Performed several more tests and I believe it has to do with sandboxing - as I00phole pointed out, just not sure how yet. If I hardcode a filename and use the app directory, all is good. If I hardcode another directory, it will not work.

I am not extremely familiar with sandboxing - any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Nobody is going to check every line of your code.

Comment: Is your app sandboxed?  If so are you bookmarking those URLs using a security-scoped bookmark?

Comment: Yes, app is sandboxed. No, I do not use any security-scoped bookmark. The backup path URL for creating the backup is from 'NSOpenPanel' and the file name is generated at runtime with a timestamp. I was reversing the process for restoring, grabbing the URL using `NSOpenPanel`.